# oci8 driver:bad connection intermittently

Tags: oracle, go, oci8

I have been using oci8 for over a year now for several batch processes. There I used to make oracle calls based on a particular frequency without any high number of parallel requests. Recently I started using this driver to process multiple number of user requests in parallel using go routines. The connections go through 90% of the times but for remaining 10% I see an error `driver: bad connection` being thrown from this driver. This is generally happening in two situations:

1. When the connection was left idle for too long(happens for few requests).
2. When there is a spike in number of connections.

Actions taken:

1. Already checked with my oracle DB for connection/session limits. There is no such limit on it.
2. Tried forking the branch and adding error logs which didn't seem to compile.
   Most of the people who have faced this issue mentioned wrong handling of multiple connections at the same time. For me that is something done by oci8.

Please help!

Comment: Oracle always has a limit on the number of processes/sessions. If not specified sessions is derived from processes. How many connections are you peaking at and what are your parameter values for sessions and processes?

Comment: I am peaking upto 500 sessions

Comment: Then check the processes parameter. The default value (in 12c) is computed based on the number of cores and sessions is computed as (again in 12c) 1.5*processes+22.

Comment: I having 2000 processes configured.

Comment: It may be that Oracle runs out of memory or something and kills connections. Have you checked the alert log on the database server? Plus you should check if you have a firewall in between, that can explain the problem with lost idle connections. Many firewalls cut connections that have been idle for a while.

Comment: There is nor firewall in between and my logs don't show up any memory issues.

Comment: I was able to find the exact error message: `ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE` not sure how to mitigate this.